# Как сделать автоимпорт в Intelij Idea java библиотек через репозиторий Maven. Сам проект без фреймворка Maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Как сделать автоимпорт в Intelij Idea библиотек через репозиторий Maven, чтобы 100 раз не ходить через структуру проекта и настройки для добавления по отдельности.

[image: Пример 1]
[image: Пример 2]

Comment: то, что вы хотите, без указания в pom.xml - невозможно. либо вы весь репозиторий выкачиваете локально к себе.

Comment: было бы удобно, если Intelij Idea сама скачивала недостающие библиотеки, ведь она видит эти пакеты через свой maven репозиторий. Жаль что у ней нет такой функции. Много часов могла бы спасти =)

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте флаг: "Import Maven projects automatically" по пути:

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing

Comment: Поставил соответствующую галочку, но к сожалению все-равно при открытии проектов не Maven, приходится идти в настройки и искать библиотеку. Я прикрепил скриншоты.

Comment: @АнатолийСолнцевский, неправильно понял Вас без скриншотов, это для автоимпорта, если прописали сами депенденси в pom

Answer (score 0):

Подождите когда появится всплывающие окно, позволяющее установить флаг, чтобы автоматически синхронизировать конфигурацию Maven проекта и IJ проекта.

Эта опция также доступна в свойствах Maven проекта, там надо поставить галочку для автоматической синхронизации.